# Is reading a youtube video only for sound possible in command line?

Tags: mediaplayer

I would like to connect to YouTube and read a video only for audio with commands. Is that possible?

Comment: VLC can play Youtube videos, you should fiddle around with the command line options to disable GUI, video and tell it the correct audio device to use

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To download the audio as `mp3`, naming the file including the authors name and the video title, use:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 '<URL>'
```

For example, to download that interesting talk of Linus on `git`, and include the uploader's name in the file name (*),

`youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --output '%(uploader)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8'`

will save the audio as file
`Google-Tech Talk - Linus Torvalds on git.mp3`

**To date**, this needs to **download the full video** data, and **split the audio** part off, discarding the images.
But it is **expected** that it will be possible to **download just the audio** track **soon**, with one of the next updates of `youtube-dl`, combined with changes at the YouTube server side.

`youtube-dl` then uses `ffmpeg` to convert the downloaded `.m4a` file to the `.mp3` format.

To make the command line shorter, options can be saved in the config file:
`~/.config/youtube-dl.conf`

<sub>* `-x` is the short form of `--extract-audio`</sub>

Comment: It do not work: [download] 100% of _size_ .MiB in _time_ 
ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one. I think it is because of ffmpeg.

Comment: @aleroy Yes, right. (Try apt-get install ffmpeg or equivalent)

Comment: All this suppose to download the video but what if we do not download it, but we just read it? How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "just read"? The audio is mixed with the video in one file, so we need to get that file first.

Comment: Why are you passing in `--restrict-filenames`? That's not necessary at all. Also note that any recent version of youtube-dl [does only download the audio for YouTube videos](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/de3ef3ed/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L627).

Comment: @phihag `--restrict-filenames` removes various "special" characters from the output file name - if there are any, in title or author name.

Comment: @phihag Interesting - so there is support for audio-only from YouTube side now? So I need to revise the commands...

Comment: @Volker Siegel I'm well aware of that (given that I wrote the option), but what is the problem with these special characters? The OP is on Mac OSX, and unless he's using a really weird combination (like a thumb drive with a FAT32 filesystem from another locale) all characters should be supported.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Yes, see [user287782's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145438/5303). Unfortunately, the exact file format of YouTube's audio-only files is not supported by all music players.

Comment: Sure, I tried to express that I was not aware of it, and pleasantly surprised! On the filename characters: I do not have an example, but remember there were name examples that were technically valid file names (on ext4), but were hard to use in the shell. The option fixed that. Maybe it was just the "&" and the spaces (possibly leading spaces).

Comment: @VolkerSiegel The ampersand is only a problem if you type out the whole name, and I don't know who would do that. I don't think a lot of people use a shell without tab completion. I've proposed an edit to simplify the answer. youtube-dl will filter out completely unreasonable characters in the file name automatically.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I wanted something to read the music without downloading it, extracting the music from the video in cahce or something... But that's great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `youtube-dl -f bestaudio <URL>` to download the audio of the video and `mplayer` to play it.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have `mplayer`, and I don't want to install it. Do you know one that is already installed on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: aleroy, you will need to install *something*, why not `mplayer`?

Comment: @Alexander I finally did it, the website did not makes me trust it. But whatever, how can I now put this in background? (not suspended with `Ctrl+Z`)

Comment: just type `bg` after pressing `ctrl-z`, or better, use `tmux`

Comment: Or put an ampersand `&` at the end of the command before running it.

Comment: @Alexander thank you, I discovered Tmux and it is very powerful.

Comment: @Khaelix The problem with the ampersand (and ^Z) is that it stops the music.